# Logical Propositions: Which two cards will verify the statement is true?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation

Problem: I tell you that if a card has a vowel on one side, then it has an odd number on the other side. Right now, you see symbols E, S, 3, and 8 on the sides that are up. So, what are the minimum amount of cards you must check to verify the statement is true?

Teacher's Answer:
Let P = "the card has a vowel", Q = "the card has an odd number on one side"

We lift the vowel E, because if it's false, the statement P --> Q is false.

We don't lift S, because if the statement P --> Q is true, Q can be true regardless of P.

We don't lift 3, because again, Q can be true regardless of P.

We lift 8, because according to the statement not Q --> not P, P --> Q is false if the card has a vowel.

My question:
The statement P --> Q is equivalent to "not P or Q". So, can we verify the original statement is true by knowing that S is not a vowel (equivalent to not P), and 3 is an odd number (equivalent to Q)? This way, you could verify the statement with just 1 card instead of 2?

Comment: P --> Q = ¬P or Q. By just knowing that S is not a vowel (and thus equivalent to ¬P), can we confirm the original statement is true?

Comment: The statement has to be true of every card so you have to check all cards that could be counter-examples. There are two such cards (by your teacher's reasoning) and you must check them both.